# Aptana and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, aptana

I'm giving a try to Aptana Studio 2 IDE, but before changing my current IDE (which is NetBeans 6.9) I'd like to know if it does a good integration with Zend Framework. Can I use Zend_Tool for example?

What do you guys think about Aptana + Zend Framework coding?

Comment: Why do you want to switch to Aptana from Netbeans?

Comment: To be honest the only IDE i would consider switching to from Netbeans is PhpStorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion on IDE's for Zend Framework I have tried so far:

1. Zend Studio
2. Netbeans 7 (refactoring!)
3. Eclipse PDT
4. Others (including Aptana)

So, I'd stick with Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/) is in beta I've been using it for a while. It's not ideal but it's a beta after all and the updates have been fairly regular. Code Assist only works if you have a copy of the ZF library in the project you are working on but there is plans to add [external library support](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/701-will-aptana-3-support-php-frameworks-such-as-zend-framework).
If you're happy with NetBeans I would stick with it but keep your eye on the [release notes](http://aptana.com/products/studio3/releasenotes).